# Cannot create the log info and directory, while using Conda environment

Tags: exception, logging, conda, python-dataclasses, virtual-environment

its suppose to be creating an 'artifacts' folder with train, test, and data.csv in it, but it doesn't. This problem is from Krish Naik tutorial of End to end Data Science Project. This code is supposed to be a Data Ingestion code for splitting train and test data.

the exception.py and logger.py module are stored in parent directory.
This is the data_ingestion.py files code looks like:

```
import os
import sys
from src.exception import CustomException
from src.logger import logging
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class DataIngestionConfig:
    train_data_path: str=os.path.join('artifacts',"train.csv")
    test_data_path: str=os.path.join('artifacts',"test.csv")
    raw_data_path: str=os.path.join('artifacts',"data.csv")

class DataIngestion:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ingestion_config=DataIngestionConfig()

    def initiate_data_ingestion(self):
        logging.info("Entered the data ingestion method or component")
        try:
            df=pd.read_csv('notebook\data\stud.csv')
            logging.info('Read the dataset as dataframe')

            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(self.ingestion_config.train_data_path), exist_ok=True)

            df.to_csv(self.ingestion_config.raw_data_path, index=False, header=True)
            logging.info("train test split initiated")
            train_set, test_set = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

            train_set.to_csv(self.ingestion_config.train_data_path, index= False, header=True)

            test_set.to_csv(self.ingestion_config.test_data_path, index= False, header=True)
            logging.info("ingestion of data is completed")

            return(
                self.ingestion_config.train_data_path,
                self.ingestion_config.test_data_path
            )

        except Exception as e:
            raise CustomException(e,sys)
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    obj=DataIngestion()
    obj.initiate_data_ingestion
```

the logger.py :

```
import logging
import os
from datetime import datetime

LOG_FILE=f"{datetime.now().strftime('%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S')}.log"
logs_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"logs",LOG_FILE)
os.makedirs(logs_path,exist_ok=True)

LOG_FILE_PATH=os.path.join(logs_path,LOG_FILE)

logging.basicConfig(
    filename=LOG_FILE_PATH,
    format="[ %(asctime)s ] %(lineno)d %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
    level=logging.INFO,
)
```

and the exception.py :

```
import sys
from src.logger import logging

def error_message_detail(error,error_detail:sys):
    _,_,exc_tb=error_detail.exc_info()
    file_name=exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename
    error_message="Error occured in python script name [{0}] line number [{1}] error message[{2}]".format(
     file_name,exc_tb.tb_lineno,str(error))

    return error_message

    

class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self,error_message,error_detail:sys):
        super().__init__(error_message)
        self.error_message=error_message_detail(error_message,error_detail=error_detail)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.error_message
```

The data_ingestion.py file is running perfectly:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4k0o.png)

but the artifacts directory, train.csv, and test.csv are not being created. Is there a problem within the code, or the Conda environment I'm using? please help